# How do you stream an upload to S3 via node.js and show progress to user?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, jquery-file-upload, busboy

The goal is to:

1. Be able to upload a file from browser
2. Be able to stream the upload directly to S3
3. Relay the upload progress to browser

It took me a while to figure this out (and didn't quite find an answer to do all 3 on StackOverflow yet) so posting my answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

I'm open to suggestions to better solutions (the speeds on mine are pretty horrible).

Answer (score 5):

On Frontend HTML

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="files[]">
```

On Frontend JS

```
require('blueimp-file-upload');
var socket = require('socket.io-client');

var fileSize;
var socketId;

// Socket will be used to transmit the percent uploaded from server
socket.connect()
  // when the socket gives us a unique ID we will save it so that we
  // can identify the client
  .on('id', function (data) {
    socketId = data;
  })

  .on('uploadProgress', function (data){
    // you can show a progress bar with this percentage 
    var pct = data.loaded / fileSize;
  });

$('.file')
    .change(function (){
        // save the file size so that we can calculate perfectage
        fileSize = this.files[0].size;  
    })
    .fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .fileupload('option', {
        url: '/upload?socketId=' + socketId
    });
```

On Server

```
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

// Set up Express
var app = express();
var server = http
    .Server(app)
    .listen(80);

var io = socket(server);

// keeps track of all the open sockets
var sockets = {};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var uniqueId = _.random(0, 100000000);
  app.socket[uniqueId] = socket;
  socket.emit('id', uniqueId);
});

// Set up upload route
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
        AWS.config.update({
            appKey: '',
            jsKey: '',
        });
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        var busboy = new Busboy({
            headers: req.headers 
        });

    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
        s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'bucketname',
            Key: new Date().getTime() + filename,
            Body: file //stream
        }, function(err, file){
            res.json({
                success: true
            });
        }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { 
            //emit progress
            sockets[req.query.socketId].emit('uploadProgress', evt);
        });
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Comment: The one problem I'm having is slow upload speeds so open to better suggestions.

Comment: I thing you should put `file.on('data', function(data) {` after `busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {`